# Can't format USB Stick

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, readonly, read-write

Ok so here's what happened.

I had been using a USB stick to re-install Windows 10 and quickly reformat my dads laptop. Now I used the existing Windows 10 to create the live USB drive and I guess it write protected the stick.

Now I've been trying a bunch of things to get my stick back:

- Bootice
- Gparted (Format to, Delete)
- Windows Disk Utility
- Linux (Cinnamon?) Disk Utility
- Dispart (clean, recover)
- Windows quick format

So I pretty much am just getting errors

> Unable to format because of I/O Error
>
> Unable to open drive read-write. Drive opened read-only
>
> Unable to format because it's opened read-only

If you have any suggestions on what to do. I have a Linux and a Windows 10 installation so I can try both :)

Comment: Is it possible that the USB stick hardware got corrupted?

Comment: Sure but I noticed right after installing Win10 with it.

Comment: I had a similar issue with an external usb hdd. Not sure if it'll help with yours but using Ubuntu 14.04 as root not sudo worked. For sudo I kept getting permission error so as root I chmod 777 the entire usb hdd then formatted as root and all was well.

Comment: Analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Your USB stick is in read-only mode because it is failing. All attempts at low-level manipulation (fdisk etc) will mysteriously fail.

Recover your data. SD cards provide the same feature before absolute failure, it’s very handy. If only Windows/etc reported the failure... wouldn’t that be great?

See https://superuser.com/a/543116

Answer (score 0):

**"Clean" the partition table and file allocation tables.**

**1**: Zero out partition table... and a little more

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=2048 count=4
```

**2**: Create partitions (use cli "fdisk" or gui "gparted")

*Create partition table "**msdos**"*

*Create partition(s) (NTFS fat32 ext3 ...)*

*Format partitions. (gparted does the partition creation and format in 1 step when you choose the partition type)*

**3**: test USB

**Tools**:

- "live" OS is perferred but not required.
- partition creation program like gparted or fdisk
- PC to work on. A virtual machine will do.

**Example**:

Boot from the "live" ISO parted magic in a virtual machine. I prefer [PartedMagic](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/parted_magic.html) because everything I need is there in one ISO.

Pass through the USB to the virtual machine. `/dev/sdx`

Using this live ISO, remember that you are root and please verify that the correct drive is passed through to the virtual machine because if you inadvertently erase the wrong drive there is no undo.

Proceed with step 1.

Comment: I'm getting "failed to open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system"

Comment: Not good. What command, and OS is giving you this error? Are you able to delete the partitions with gparted?

Comment: the exact commands would be: "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=2048 count=4" and "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2048 count=4". I am using Antergos. I am not able to do anything with gparted.

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2048 count=4` would be the one you want because it is "outside" of the partitions. The drive must not be mounted at this time.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`, or `sudo fdisk -l`. Also if no gparted you could attempt to delete a partition with `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`. If you could zero out the partition table there would not be any partitions to delete, but you could create them with fdisk.

Comment: I'm guessing the relevant parts are: disklabel type is dos, disk identifier is 0x8da0fd7e.  https://pastebin.com/18Md9Xpr I pasted it over at pastebin if that's alright?

Answer (score 0):

jc__'s answer regarding zeroing the drive first & recreating the partitions first would be my first go-to, I don't have enough reputation to comment though, that if that's still not doing anything you might want to try

```
hdparm -r 0 [device]
```

and

```
blockdev --setrw [device]
```

to change hard drive parameters